# Thread safety on local ArrayList object

Tags: java, multithreading

Needed one clarification in understanding :

```
public class Dummy {

    public void function1() {
       final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
       function2(list)
       .
       .
       .
       list.addAll(…);
       .
       .
    }

    private void function2(List<String> list) {
        .
        .
        list.add(…);
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Since the add method on ArrayList is not thread safe but here we are dealing with ArrayList as local variables only --- so can it still cause thread safety related issues ?

Wanted to know if above one is thread safe or not ? If not , why is it so ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? The state isn't shared with threads (unless you are doing really ugly things).

Comment: I was having problems trying to phrase out what I wanted to say earlier, but I found this post that conveys what I was trying to say: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/347376/426931

Comment: Nothing in your example shows the `list` being given to another thread. There is no thread-safety issue if only one thread ever uses it.

Answer (score 2):

As a general sketch, this seems fine: you create an object locally, only ever refer to it via the local variable and it doesn't escape to any other thread. Therefore no threading-complications should happen.

**But** the "..." does a lot of work, and depending on what exactly you do there, you *could* introduce issues.

The most obvious problem would be something like

```
new Thread(() -> { ...; list.add(...); ... }).start();
```

Similarly, but perhaps more subtle would be something like [`Collection.parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream()):

```
someOtherCollection.parallelStream().forEach(o -> { ...; list.add(...); ... });
```

In both of those cases your `list` would escape to other thread and the whole thing could potentially get problems.